# How to store just a part of a return statement

Tags: java, variables

I have the following code. I want to store just the variable `dateStore` in another variable of type String. I have searched the web thoroughly but found nothing, so I was hoping that you guys can help! How shall I go about to do this please?

```
public String orderTime(){
    String dateStore = "";
    String time = "";
    if(!out){
        GregorianCalendar orderDay = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
        time = timeFormat.format(new Date());
        System.out.println (); 
        dateStore = sdf.format(orderDay.getTime());
    } 
    return "Date of Order: " + dateStore +
    "Time of Order: " + time +
    "=============================================";
}
```

Basically, I am doing an order program. It displays the time of the order through the use of the `orderTime()` method. Now, I want to display all orders at a specific date, so I thought i have to store the `dateStore` variable to another variable, so that I can use it in another method to insert it into the Vector for comparison purposes later on. Sorry if THIS IS NOT CLEAR, i am trying to explain it my best.

Comment: You'll need to extract it from the string, or – better yet – re-design `orderTime` to return a more useful data structure.

Comment: Can you please restate your question? dateStore is already of type String... you mean outside of the scope of the method?

Comment: Why are you returning more than you want? You probably want to refactor it into multiple functions with a shared function backing them, or make it return a suitable data structure.

Comment: Very strange question. You can just do "String otherVar = dateStore;" ? I think you need to clarify your question

Comment: @5gon12eder Hi thanks for the comment. What exactly do you mean by extracting it from the String please? Sorry I am still learning Java.

Comment: Hi all... i edited a bit the question, maybe it could help you. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Extracting it from the string should only be your last resort if you cannot change the method.  You'll need [`String.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) and [`String.substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-). But prefer changing your return type as shown in [Elliott Frisch's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27969190/1392132).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, modify your method (or add another method) to return `dateStore`. Something like

```
public String orderDate(){
    if(!out){
        GregorianCalendar orderDay = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy");
        return sdf.format(orderDay.getTime());
    } 
    return "";
}
```

If you want to return date and time as a unit, then I suggest you create a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) like

```
public class DateAndTime {
  final String date;
  final String time;
  public DateAndTime(String date, String time) {
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Date of Order: " + date +
      "Time of Order: " + time +
      "=============================================";
  }
}
```

And then return a `DateAndTime` instance from your method like

```
public DateAndTime orderTime(){
    String dateStore = "";
    String time = "";
    if(!out){
        GregorianCalendar orderDay = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
        time = timeFormat.format(new Date());
        // System.out.println (); 
        dateStore = sdf.format(orderDay.getTime());
    } 
    return new DateAndTime(dateStore, time);
}
```

Because the POJO overrides `toString()` you can print it and get your original output String.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for... however the thing is that I want to also return the time. Shall I return the time is the second return statement? And how would another method now which return value to store? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFarrugia Either concatenate it into one String, return a Java Date (which includes time), or use a POJO like my edit above.

Comment: I vote for adding another method.  It makes the calling code more readable.  The caller asks for the order date, it gives you the order date.

Comment: @ajb Hmm it makes much more sense... did not think of that lol. Thanks

Comment: @DavidFarrugia Did you miss the first part of my answer?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes of course... I am working on your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] orderTime(){
    String dateStore = "";
    String time = "";
    if(!out){
        GregorianCalendar orderDay = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
        time = timeFormat.format(new Date());
        System.out.println (); 
        dateStore = sdf.format(orderDay.getTime());
    } 
    String[] aReturn = new String[2];
    aReturn[0] = "Date of Order: " + dateStore;
    aReturn[1] = "Time of Order: " + time;
    return aReturn;
}
```

Then you can access these two string values separately.

Comment: I would generally argue that using an array as a tuple replacement to return multiple values is a bad idea - it makes your code much more cryptic and awkward to use. This also doesn't give just `dateStore` which was what the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The user did not say he just want to return dateStore. The requirement was to store just the variable dateStore in another variable of type String. So that's why I thought returning both separately was the main concern here. The thing is, the question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an Object Orioented language - it makes doing objecty things very easy. You just need to make objects and tell them what to do.

```
public class Order {
    // Only create the formatters once.
    static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy");
    static final SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    static {
        timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
    }
    // Grab the current date/time at creation time.
    final GregorianCalendar orderDay = new GregorianCalendar();
    final Date time = new Date();

    // What was the date of the order.
    public String getDate() {
        return sdf.format(orderDay);
    }

    // What was the time of the oorder.
    public String getTime() {
        return timeFormat.format(time);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // A nice representation of the Order.
        return "Date of Order: " + getDate()
                + "Time of Order: " + getTime()
                + "=============================================";
    }
}

public Order newOrder() {
    return new Order();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 to OldCurmudgeon

You just have to declare the orderDay variable as member of your class

```
public class Order {
private GregorianCalendar orderDay;
...
```

change the line

```
GregorianCalendar orderDay = new GregorianCalendar();
```

by

```
this.orderDay = new GregorianCalendar();
```

and add this. before each orderDay

Do the same for the time and 
after create getters to get values in differents format

```
public GregorianCalendar get_orderDay() {
   Return this.orderDay;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

There is a lot of improvements that we could do to that methods, but focusing on your question, you may use an output parameter, it is easier to read and undestand.

```
public String orderTime(String out dateStore){
    dateStore = "";
```

Comment: It's also highly illegal in Java.  Maybe they'll give it to us in Java 9?

Comment: @ajb Java 10. The X makes it sexy.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure I'd go with this solution even if I were using C#.  It's still bad for readability--you ask the object for the order time, and it gives you this extra junk that the name `orderTime` doesn't reflect.